# Deadlock caused by creating a new thread during class initialization

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I just noticed that creating and starting a number of threads, during a class' static initialization, results in a deadlock and none of the threads getting started. This problem disappears if I run the same code dynamically, after the class has been initialized. Is this expected behavior?

Short sample program:

```
package com.my.pkg;

import com.google.common.truth.Truth;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class MyClass {
    private static final Collection<Integer> NUMS = getNums();

    @Test
    public void fork_doesNotWorkDuringClassInit() {
        // This works if you also delete NUMS from above: 
        // Truth.assertThat(getNums()).containsExactly(0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
        Truth.assertThat(NUMS).containsExactly(0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
    }

    private static Collection<Integer> getNums() {
        return IntStream.range(0, 5)
                        .mapToObj(i -> fork(() -> i))
                        .map(MyClass::get)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static <T> FutureTask<T> fork(Callable<T> callable) {
        FutureTask<T> futureTask = new FutureTask<>(callable);
        Thread thread = new Thread(futureTask);
        thread.start();
        return futureTask;
    }

    public static <T> T get(Future<T> future) {
        try {
            return future.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Thread thread = new Thread(futureTask);` ==> bad.
`Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(callable);` ==> good. You shouldn't start threads manually, use [executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).

Comment: Well no, that *isn't* a program.  It's not even a complete class.  Present a [mcve] if you want troubleshooting help.

Comment: @alfasin, That's a dogmatic answer.  There are reasons for using an `ExecutorService`,  and there are reasons for creating naked `Thread` objects.  Some of the arguments against calling `new Thread(...)` can be dealt with by calling `threadFactory.newThread(...)` instead.

Comment: I'm not all that knowledgeable about streams, but this looks like a no-op: `.collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()`.  Am I wrong, or does that just a round-about way of turning a stream of T into a stream of T?

Comment: @jameslarge you're right about your second comment. As for your first - this is a comment that calls out a bad practice. It is, by no means, intended to be an answer.

Comment: @alfasin The sample program above isn't intended to be good code. Rather, it's intended to highlight surprising behavior which I'm trying to better understand.

Comment: @jameslarge The .collect(...).stream() looks like a nop, but it actually makes a huge difference. Suppose the work being offloaded to the thread involves slow network calls. With the intermediate "nop", all the threads are first started, and then all the future.get() happen sequentially. If you eliminate the "nop", this completely changes. The N+1 thread is only created/started, after the Nth thread has completely finished. All parallelism is lost by getting rid of the "nop".

That said, the above point is not relevant to the deadlock that's being hit, so I've removed it for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior.

The basic issue here is that you are attempting to access the class from another thread before class initialization is complete.  It happens to be another thread that you start during class initialization, but that doesn't make any difference.

In Java, classes are initialized lazily, at first reference.  When a class has not completed initialization, threads that reference the class attempt to obtain the class initialization lock.  The first thread to obtain the class initialization lock initializes the thread, and that initialization must complete before the other threads can proceed.

In this case, `fork_doesNotWorkDuringClassInit()` starts initialization, obtaining the class initialization lock.  However, initialization spawns additional threads, which attempt to call the lambda callable `() -> i`. The callable is a member of the class, so these threads are then blocked on the class initialization lock, which is held by the thread that started the initialization.

Unfortunately, your initialization process requires the results from the other threads before initialization can be completed.  It blocks on those results, which are in turn blocked on the initialization completion.  The threads end up deadlocked.

More information on class initialization here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2

In general, Java initializers and constructors are limited in what they can do - considerably more limited than is the case in, say, C++.  This can prevent certain types of errors, but can also restrict what you can do.  This is an example of one of those restrictions.

Comment: Very interesting. One question though. You mentioned: "initialization spawns additional threads, which attempt to call the class's  get() method. These threads are then blocked on the class initialization lock". I'm seeing that the deadlock still occurs, even if I move the get() method entirely outside the class. Why is that? Why do the new threads continue to be blocked by the class initialization lock, even though they aren't accessing any class variables/methods?

Comment: What do you mean by "entirely outside the class"? Show some code. You can also run `jstack` to see exactly how the deadlock manifests (and you could include the output). Note also that `fork()` is called in the context of the other thread and would have to be moved too. @RvPr

Comment: @BeeOnRope I had literally cut-pasted the get(Future) method into another class, outside of MyClass. I had done this based on Warren's comment that "initialization spawns additional threads, which attempt to call the class's  get() method". But now as I look closer, I realize that the additional threads are actually not calling the get method. The only task they are running is the "() -> i" callable. And even if I replaced the "i" with a hardcoded "5", it still deadlocks. I'm wondering when and at what point the additional threads try to acquire the class lock

Comment: @BeeOnRope Just tried one last experiment where I replaced the ```() -> i``` with ```OtherClass::methodReturningInt```, and the deadlock now disappears. It appears that the ```() -> i``` lambda is linked to MyClass such that when the threads try to access it, they deadlock. But when they call a callable that resides entirely elsewhere, there is no deadlock anymore.

Comment: Run a `jstack` to find out, but mostly post your updated code since now you are speculating about private code that no one can see or easily run. The `() -> i` lambda itself is probably a member of the class, and you can't easily move that out while keeping it a lambda.

Comment: Our comments crossed in transit, but yeah, the lambda is usually implemented as a hidden inner/nested class of the declaring class, so it will also need to wait for static init of the containing class.

Comment: @RvPr Thanks for following up.  Accepted your edit referencing the lambda callable instead of the get() function with a little editorial adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

During class static initialization, a lock is held on the class itself to block *other* threads which try to use the class so they wait for the static initialization to complete. This is often referred to as the "classloader lock" or the "static init" lock<sup>1</sup>.

If the code doing static initialization calls tries to access other static state of the class *on the same thread*, you won't get a deadlock since the lock is recursive and allows the owning thread back in: this is required by the JLS. This also applies to recursive initialization where the static init for `class A` ends up triggering the initialization of `class B` whose static init ultimately accesses static state in `class A`. While it won't deadlock, you'll often see the default values (e.g., `null`, `0`, etc) for static members which haven't been initialized yet.

When you trigger the same type of situation as describe above *across threads*, you get a deadlock, since the static init lock won't let other threads back in.

---

<sup>1</sup> The former name is not necessary accurate since the classloader itself may internally use *other* locks to protect its structures beyond the static init lock.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Appreciate it.